# Jinja2 browser load

Tags: python, frameworks, jinja2

I am able to execute the python file through shell like so:

$ python jinja.py

[code]
    from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

```
DIR = '/Users/username/Sites'

env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader(DIR))

templateVars = {
    "title" : "Test Example",
    "description" : "Description"
    }

template = env.get_template('index.html')

print template.render(templateVars)
```

[/code]

Here is the ouput via the shell:

[code]

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Example</title>
<meta name="description" content="Description">
</head>
<body>

test dictionary

</body>
</html>
```

[/code]

However, when I pull up index.html on the browser it doesn't render the variable, I am not sure the file jinja.py is even being executed.

Here is the sourcecode directly from my the browser window:

[code]

```
<html>
<head>
<title>{{ title }}</title>
<meta name="description" content="{{ description }}">
</head>
<body>

test dictionary

</body>
</html>
```

[/code]

Fyi, I am not using jinja2 in conjunction with any frameworks or other package dependencies.

Anyone able to help out.

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your http://www.example.com/index.html should GET a script, which uses jinja to render the HTML.
You need a framework like webapp2 in Google App Engine to handle the GET.

I found this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XyGW0ExGHDQ
Or use: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/introduction

Comment: Thanks vocausa - so Jinja2 doesn't work independently. A framework like webapp2 or google app engine is mandatory for it to work.

Comment: YES, Jinja is only for rendering pages. You need a handler to handle your requests. I prefer webapp2 (Googles choice for GAE) , but you can use lots of others: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks